# how to use replace to replace string names found in query

Tags: mysql, replace, mysql-function

I have the following table :

[image]

and on the other side I have a string that can contain words from the above table , ex:
"Jeff El ABC THE DEF"

I need to do the following :

```
REPLACE("Jeff El ABC THE DEF", Select words from table,"");
```

So I need to remove any word found in the query result , any suggestions ?

Example:

input: "Jeff EL ABC THE DEF"
query result : words[EL, THE, AL]
expected output: "Jeff ABC DEF"

Comment: can you share any example of your output

Comment: The characters you want to replace "Jeff El" etc are particular or could be any other characters as well?

Comment: depends on the table , so in future I can add another redundant words